# Booting BIOS WIM / ISO Capture files in UEFI Mode

Tags: vmware-esxi

We're in the process of upgrading ESXi from an older version that only supported BIOS boot mode and I've got some questions around Windows Images (wim files) that we've captured from those VM's that are running on the older version of ESXi and what happens when I upgrade and my VM's start running under UEFI mode.

As we're still in the planning stage, mainly I'm looking for some general advice and guidance on how best to make use of these images in WDS once the migration is complete. I suppose the first question I have is whether or not these images will even be usable once the upgrade is complete - will images captured on VM's running in BIOS mode still be usable and deployable to VM's running in EFI mode?

And if not, what's the process to get them running again? Is there a way to convert those images work with UEFI mode or would they have to be rebuilt from scratch?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dont care about the virtualisation server, it doesnt need to think about - remind like hyper-v, can be installed on UEFI and BIOS and in case of the first, you can still choose between type 1 (bios) or type 2 (UEFI), or dont you? :-) and in case something goes wrong, since you are here on a business Platform, you hopefully paid the VM support....(!)

Answer (score 0):

Changing your host is not going to change your virtual machines. They are not going to change from BIOS to UEFI because the host has changed.

Comment: Yea, I know they won't suddenly change over, but I'm curious as to whether the ISO's / templates that I've built and imported into WDS will still be valid once the upgrade is made.